# Is the series $S_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \sin n x }{n^{\log_e n}}$ converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}?$

Tags: real-analysis

Is the  series $S_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \sin n x }{n^{\log_e n}}$ converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}?$

My attempt :I think **No**

Im using the  Dirichlet test for uniform convergence

Take $f_n(x)= \frac{1}{\log_e n}$ and  $g_n(x)= (-1)^n \sin n x$

$|\sum g_n(x)|= | \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin kx|\le \frac{1}{\sin \frac{x}{2}}$

$\sin (x/2)  = 0 $ if  $x = 2n\pi$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Therefore  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \sin n x }{n^{\log_e n}}$ is converge  only for  $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{2n\pi : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: What happens if you put $x=\pi k$, $k\in \mathbb Z$ into the defintion of $S_n$?

Comment: $S_n=\infty$  @Gary

Comment: Are you sure? $\sin(n \pi k)=0$ for all $n\geq 1$, so $S_n=0$, isn't it? Also your claim that $\sin(x/2)=0$ if $x=\pi n$, $n\in \mathbb Z$ is not completely correct. Try $n=1$. The correct form is $x=2\pi n$.

Comment: My question is about   series  **NOT** sequence @Gary

Comment: $\sum \sin (n\pi k) \neq 0$ @Gary

Comment: Ok, let me go to baby level: $$
S_n (\pi k) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n \sin (n\pi k)}}{{n^{\log _e n} }}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n 0}}{{n^{\log _e n} }}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty 0= 0
$$

Comment: okay got it @Gary thanks for help

Comment: Please correct the claim about $\sin(x/2)$ in your question. It is zero iff $x=2\pi n$.

Comment: @Gary $$| \sum \sin kx| = \left| \sin x + \sin 2x + \cdots + \sin nx \right| = \left|\frac{\sin{\frac{nx}{2}}\sin {\frac{(n+1)x}{2}}}{\sin{\frac{x}{2}}}\right| \le \frac{1}{\left|\sin{\frac{x}{2}}\right|} $$
  and $\frac{1}{\left|\sin{\frac{x}{2}}\right|} \in \Bbb{R}$  if  $x \ne 2\pi$.

Comment: Yes you are right i edited @Gary

Comment: I edited i think $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \sin n x }{n^{\log_e n}}$ is converge  only for  $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{2n\pi : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ @Gary

Comment: Oh god. Didn't we just agree that $S_n=0$ for $x=2\pi k$? You just have to consider the case $x=2\pi k$ separately by plugging it into the formula for $S_n$.

Comment: Also, $\left| {\sum {g_n (x)} } \right| = \left| {\sum {( - 1)^n \sin (nx)} } \right|$ and not $
\left| {\sum {\sin (nx)} } \right|$. It is not the same.

Comment: okay i thought that both are same @Gary

Comment: It is like saying $\left| {1 - 2 + 3-4} \right| = \left| {1 + 2 + 3+4} \right|$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\log_e(n) > 2$ for $n > e^2$ and
$|(-1)^n \sin(nx)| \le 1$,
$\left|\frac{(-1)^n \sin n x }{n^{\log_e n}}\right|
\lt \frac1{n^2}
$
so the sum converges.